# Trying to use JavaScript to send generated text to specific P tags

Tags: javascript, html, xcode

In an iPhone app i have started to develop, I have created some sample text using PhoneGap's FileWriter API document, and then used FileReader to read the file back to the user. Currently the file is displayed in a separate HTML page and it need to go to specific `<p>` tags with the id 'mytext'.

```
function readmyfile(){
  var myPara = documentGetElementById("mytext");
  myPara.write(text);
 }
```

- 'mytext' is the id in the `<p>` tags and 'text' is the sample text created by a different function.

the first line of the function definelty works, it's the second that's the problem. I need the app to send the sample text to the `<p>` tags and i'm not sure how to do that.

If you need any more info or code just comment it and i'll put it in an edit.

Comment: myPara.innerHTML = text;

Comment: Unless you've defined it somewhere, there is no `documentGetElementById` function. There is, though, a `document.getElementById` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTMLElements don't have a `write` method.  You want to write to the `innerHTML` or `innerText` property.

```
var myPara = document.getElementById("mytext");
myPara.innerText = text;
```

Answer (score 1):

For getting the object, you will need this:

```
document.getElementById("mytext");
```

You will need to use `innerText` or `textContent` to actually write text in to the `p` element.

Try:

```
myPara.innerText = text;
```

or

```
myPara.textContent = text;
```